# Testing Pre-Built Command Event

Tags: visual-studio-2012, command-line, pre-build-event

Is there anyway I can test pre-built event command line, from visual studio command prompt or from any other tool?
I have this event

```
REM C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe $(SolutionDir). $(SolutionDir)\mynamespace\Release.tmpl $(SolutionDir)\mynamespace\Release.txt
```

But it does not seems to work (Nothing happens). I also tried to execute this command from simple comand prompt, still without success. any help would be great.

However, if I remove the REM from the front, I get the following error message (as mentioned by @Giorgi):

> The command "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe
>   "C:\Projects\GUI\RTS\Development."
>   "C:\Projects\GUI\RTS\Development\mynamespace\Release.tmpl"
>   "C:\Projects\GUI\RTS\Development\mynamespace\Release.txt""
>   exited with code 9009.

Comment: It worked Giorgi, REM was for making it a comment. but then I added "$(SolutionDir)." which made it worked. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `REM` there.
It means that the line is a comment.
Try deleting `REM`.

Change

```
REM C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe $(SolutionDir). $(SolutionDir)\mynamespace\Release.tmpl $(SolutionDir)\mynamespace\Release.txt
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe $(SolutionDir). $(SolutionDir)\mynamespace\Release.tmpl $(SolutionDir)\mynamespace\Release.txt
```

Comment: Yes REM will add a comment "SVN Rev number" into Release.txt file. All of it was working fine until I got new computer.

Comment: @Irfan, see updated answer. Did you try removing REM?

Comment: yes @Giorgi I tried it. It gives compiler error. As I told you, before getting my new computer, everything was fine with this command. I dnt know why is it now working on new pc. Nothing is changed

Comment: You said nothing happens in your question, now you say it gives error. Can you paste error?

Comment: may be double quotes round "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe" ?